# MvxTimePicker Won't bind to a TimeSpan

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I have an android app using MvvmCross 6.0.  I am trying to bind a MvxTimePicker to a TimeSpan.  My Layout is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
  <TextView
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      style="@style/TableHeaderTextView"
      android:text="Start Time"/>
  <MvxTimePicker
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:timePickerMode="spinner"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    local:MvxBind="Value StoreOpens" />
  <Button
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="Close"
      local:MvxBind="Click CloseCommand" />
</LinearLayout>
```

My ViewModel is:

```
public class StoreOpenDialogViewModel : MvxViewModel<Site, bool>
{

    private readonly IMvxNavigationService _navigationService;

    public StoreOpenDialogViewModel(IMvxNavigationService navigationService)
    {
        _navigationService = navigationService;

        CloseCommand = new MvxAsyncCommand(async () => await _navigationService.Close(this, true));
    }

    public override System.Threading.Tasks.Task Initialize()
    {
        return base.Initialize();
    }

    public override void Prepare(Site parm)
    {
        base.Prepare();
        this.Site = parm;
    }

    public IMvxAsyncCommand CloseCommand { get; private set; }

    private Site _Site;
    public Site Site
    {
        get
        {
            return _Site;
        }
        set
        {
            _Site = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => Site);
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => StoreOpens);
        }
    }


    public TimeSpan StoreOpens
    {
        get
        {
            if (Site == null || Site.Opens == null)
                return new TimeSpan(8, 0, 0);
            else
                return Site.Opens;
        }
        set
        {
            if (Site != null)
            {
                Site.Opens = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => StoreOpens);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My View is:

```
[MvxDialogFragmentPresentation]
[Register(nameof(StoreOpenDialogView))]
public class StoreOpenDialogView : MvxDialogFragment<StoreOpenDialogViewModel>
{
    public StoreOpenDialogView()
    {
    }

    protected StoreOpenDialogView(IntPtr javaReference, JniHandleOwnership transfer)
        : base(javaReference, transfer)
    {
    }

    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        var ignore = base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

        var view = this.BindingInflate(Resource.Layout.StoreOpenDialogView, null);

        return view;
    }
}
```

This should be a pretty vanilla implementation.  Site.Opens is a TimeSpan.  When I open the dialog, I get the following error:

> [ERROR] (MvxBind) Problem seen during binding execution for binding
>   Value for StoreOpens - problem TargetInvocationException: Exception
>   has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

The dialog shows up and shows the current time.  When I try to change the time, I get:

> 04-29 21:26:55.562 I/mono-stdout(20515): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   no non-static method "Landroid/widget/TimePicker;.getHour()I"     at
>   mvvmcross.platforms.android.binding.views.MvxLayoutInflater.n_onCreateView(Native
>   Method)04-29 21:26:55.562 I/mono-stdout(20515):   at
>   mvvmcross.platforms.android.binding.views.MvxLayoutInflater.n_onCreateView(Native
>   Method)

I copied this from another project that is still running MvvmCross 5.x and it is working.  I don't know if I missed a step or if something broke in 6.0.  Anyone have any ideas about this?

Thanks,
Jim

Comment: Sounds like a linker issue. If the getter of the `Hour` property on a `TimePicker` isn't there, the linker probably stripped out the code. Add explicit usage of this property to `LinkerPleaseInclude.cs`

Comment: @Cheesebaron Thanks Cheese.  I did turn all the linking off and try it and it still messed up, but I will try your solution and see what happens.

Comment: @Cheesebaron bro I did what you said and it is still not working.  I turned linking off and cleaned and still won't work.  The strange part is that I upgraded the other project (that I actually copied the code from) to MvvmCross 6.01 and it works fine.  Is there something I might have left out?

Comment: @Cheesebaron I tried running it on an emulator with a newer Android version than the device I was testing on and it worked.  Is there a version minimum for MvxTimePicker to work?

Comment: Nope, it just enriches android TimePicker with a couple of properties. TimePicker is API 1 and up.

Comment: @Cheesebaron According to https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/91890/error-setting-timepicker-hour-property-on-android they changed the property on the TimePicker from CurrentHour to Hour in API 23.  That would account for why MvxTimePicker doesn't work below API 23.  The device I need it to work on is API 22.  Do I need to report a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the properties of the Android TimePicker changed names as of API 23.  The MvxTimePicker binds to Hour which only exists on API 23 and newer.  My workaround is as follows.  I changed the MvxTimePicker to TimePicker as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/TableHeaderTextView"
        android:text="Start Time" />
  <TimePicker
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:timePickerMode="spinner"
      android:id="@+id/tpTime"
      android:textSize="20dp" />
        <!--local:MvxBind="Value StartTime" />-->
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Close"
            style="@style/DialogButton"
            local:MvxBind="Click CloseCommand" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I changed the OnCreateView in my MvxDialogFragment to:

```
    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        var ignore = base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

        var view = this.BindingInflate(Resource.Layout.HoursStartDialogView, null);

        var tp = view.FindViewById<TimePicker>(Resource.Id.tpTime);
        if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt <= BuildVersionCodes.LollipopMr1)
        {
#pragma warning disable CS0618
            tp.CurrentHour = (Java.Lang.Integer)ViewModel.StartTime.Hours;
            tp.CurrentMinute = (Java.Lang.Integer)ViewModel.StartTime.Minutes;
        }
        else
        {
            tp.Hour = ViewModel.StartTime.Hours;
            tp.Minute = ViewModel.StartTime.Minutes;
        }

        tp.TimeChanged += (s, e) =>
        {
            ViewModel.StartTime = new TimeSpan(e.HourOfDay, e.Minute, 0);
        };

        return view;
    }
```

Yes, this is from a different app than my original question, but I fixed this one first, thus some of the name changes.  This works on earlier versions of Android.

I am going to make a bug suggestion in the MvvmCross web site, but this will get you by for now.

****  Update ****

This bug will be fixed in MvvmCross version 6.0.2 and my original post will function as expected.